# Как использовать layout в Preference?

Tags: android

Как использовать *layout* в *Preference*?

У меня есть свой дизайн настроек. Чтобы осуществить нужное, мне надо будет создавать *layout*, допустим, для *preferencesCategory*.

Но после того как я добавляю этот *layout*, почему-то не работают *title* и *sumary*, хотя я добавил *textView* вверху и внизу.

Как исправить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем layout у TextView укажите в качестве ID `@android:id/title` и `@android:id/summary`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: А я так делал не получается. У меня в Pref после этого написано TextView в названии.

Хотя нет я писал вот так   android:id="@+id/title". А почему впереди стоит android? это типо меняет стандартный textView? разве так можно

android:id="@android:id/title"

Comment: @xTIGRx  да, это разные ID. @+id/title - это ID в вашем проекте, android:id - ID в SDK андроида. Нужно именно android

Comment: @isllarionov, А почему вот так не сработало?
http://pastebin.com/Sd1XJgsz

Я как понял в Pref используется ListVIew. И по краям некий отступ есть. Вот я и создал новый listView а по краям все равно отступ остался.

Comment: этот ListView не в PreferenceCategory, а в PreferenceScreen и он не так переопределяется. Но конкретно этот  отступ вроде не в нем, а в отдельных элементах списка. Здесь могу ошибаться, не помню